# How to make a categorical choropleth map using folium

Tags: python, categorical-data, folium, choropleth

Here is my dataframe

```
    ISO_A3  Category                           Percent
0   DEU     Belletristik                        25.9
1   AUT     Ratgeber                            25.6
2   CHE     Belletristik                        27.7
3   USA     Fiction & related items             11.0
4   PRT     Mathematics & science               84.0
5   GBR     Children's, Teenage & educational   18.9
```

I want the ISO_A3 column to indicate the corresponding category with a unique colour

Comment: Geodata is required when using folium. See this reference for [more information](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb).